Emailed resignation letter on Monday, no response?
I work for an entry level billing company. I've been here a little over 2 years and found a better job opportunity elsewhere. I emailed my resignation letter Monday, it stated in the subject line "resignation" with my name and I sent it marked important to HR and my manager who wasn't there that day.
I haven't received a response yet and next week is my last week. I'm trying to see if anyone has ever had their employer not acknowledge their resignation letter.
I checked the handbook and it just says written notice was needed with 2 weeks. One of the team leads says she knows about it. But my manager never talked to me. I'm just confused...should I ask HR what my next steps are? Or give them until next week for them to respond? How long does it take for HR to respond usually?

Have you asked your manager directly?

You don’t give a country. In the UK you’d check companieshouse.gov.uk to find the official address of the company, then send your resignation to that address by registered mail, and it is legally received when the postman tries to deliver it.

@mattfreake, or a better version, "Why have you not asked your manager directly?" :)

Emails do not Solve All Problems
Emails are a good way of getting things in writing for things that do not require immediate action.  For resignations, emailing is good for getting it in writing, but as you now are experiencing there are some things that are time sensitive.  As such in these circumstances other forms of communication that can get immediate feedback should be used.  The most straight forward being directly talking to your manager.
In Person
Once your manager is back in the office, pay them a visit and make sure they are up to speed.  It is not uncommon for a manager to come back from vacation with a massive pile of emails and miss something even if it was marked as important.
Phone/Text Message
If the manager is not in the office whether it is because they are working from home, are in a different building, or some other factor then giving them a call or sending a message over whatever standard messaging software your company uses is a good alternative if you cannot talk to them in person.
Nonresponsive Manager
If directly engaging with the manager failed because they are being lazy, indifferent, hostile, distracted, or some other myriad of reasons then you need to directly engage with some other person in a leadership role that can process your resignation or directly engage someone from HR.  Either way it should be done through a form of communication that provides immediate interaction, and if you are not getting the interaction you need, you immediately move on to the next best person you can reach out to.
If you run out of people in leadership and HR that you can think of talking to, and they have done nothing, then talk to whomever senior team member like your team lead for ideas.  If they have no other ideas then just make sure to turn in all your company equipment and print out all those emails you sent and any other attempt you made to go through the resignation process.  Then on your last day say bye.  Any fireworks that happen after that are not your fault, and you have a nice stack of paper stating as much.

Document document document - if you have any company property, include ID that you return. Take pictures. Be safe, even if you don't need it.

This is a legal answer. You did not tag your question with a country, so it's anyone's guess whether this answer applies to you. If it doesn't maybe it motivates you to look into your countries laws on the matter:
In germany when something is required to be "in writing" or "written form", then a simple email does not qualify. Legally, the written form requires a manual signature. If transmitted electronically, it requires a qualified digital signature instead. This is §126a BGB. A simple email is therefor void for anything requiring written form (§125 BGB).
Now the decent move would be for HR to reply to you explaining this, waiting for your actual written form and counting the days from that date. If you are in a physical office, that might be half an hour later when you printed the email out, signed it, and brought it to HR personally. For remote work it may be three days later when the physical mail is delivered.
Just ignoring it would be a pretty shitty trick to get you to work longer. Since it is meaningless and not a valid resignation, you will at some point leave, they will tell you you cannot, everybody will be upset and arguing, but technically, legally, they would be correct and you would have to resign a second time, this time correctly, and serve that notice period, too. Whether that is a very productive notice period when they screwed you over is up for debate.
Maybe it's neither and the HR person is just out sick. Then it is even more important to do it legally correct. The company is not required to grant you a feedback channel on whether you did legal work correctly. Being sick happens.
Again, this applies in my country under those laws, you need to check your own laws whether something like this applies to you.


Make sure you have a copy of the sent email, with the date-stamp
Send a follow-up email today advising them of both your previous email and your last day, CC in a personal email address
Leave on your last day.

If you have given them your resignation and they do nothing with it - that is a company problem, not a you problem. You want to protect yourself by making sure you have proof that you sent in the resignation, but apart from that - you are under no further obligation to do anything.

Even though I strongly agree that this is a company problem, not chasing this down can negatively impact the person resigning.  There is some paperwork or information that HR does/helps with/provides when someone leaves like COBRA Insurance or how to access/rollover your 401k.  Not doing these before you leave can cause unnecessary headaches.

@Anketam - that's why you make sure you document that you have sent it and you follow it up with a second email.

Other than your last paycheck, are you expecting anything from this company?
The bottom line is they don't care about you or why you are leaving.  Just go and move on with your life.  In a way you are dead to them.
If there was equipment to be returned, such as a laptop, company phone or other "expensive" electronics you would be given on instructions on their turn in.
This just proves the old adage:  If you die, the company will have your job opening posted before your love ones write your obituary.
There really isn't much for you to do, and often it is best not to bother with the exit interview.
